# Javascript: Sending partial audio chunk from specific time range

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I'm trying to send only a part of an audio file with nodejs, say from 60 second to 100 second. I don't want to use time range `src='path/to/audio.mp3#t=60,100'` because I don't want to send the whole file from server just to play a few seconds.

So I have to send partial chunks. Problem is I don't know the byte range for the time ranges I need. I assumed that time and bytes are linear so I tried to use the time range equivalent of the total time to calculate byte ranges. It sends only the 40 second clip but it starts at the wrong time.

Please how can I get the right chunk of time.

```
var start = 60;
var end = 100;
var track = "/path/to/audio.mp3";
var total = Math.ceil(probeData.format.duration); //total length of audio in seconds

var start_ratio = (start/total);  //ratio of the starting position 
var end_ratio = (end/total);  //ratio of the ending position 

var start_chunk = Math.ceil(start_ratio * file_size); //using it on the file_size
var end_chunk = Math.ceil(end_ratio * file_size);
var chunksize = (end_chunk - start_chunk) + 1;

var file = fs.createReadStream(track, {start: start_chunk, end: end_chunk});
res.writeHead(206, {
    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start_chunk + "-" + end_chunk + "/" + file_size,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": chunksize,
    "Content-Type": "audio/mp3"
});
file.pipe(res);
```

Comment: i guess you need to parse its frames, have a look on this https://github.com/audiocogs/mp3.js/blob/master/src/decoder.js

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use time range `src='path/to/audio.mp3#t=60,100'` because I don't want to send the whole file from server just to play a few seconds.

So long as your server supports normal byte-range requests then the browser will not be fetching the whole file from your server. It will likely make two requests. First with the header `Range: bytes=0-` which it will promptly abort after it parses the necessary metadata. The it should follow it up with a second request with a header like `Range: bytes=61234-105678` or something like that which will only be fetching the required byte range to play the audio between the times you specified.

Comment: I'm using the byte-range request already, I can send the `Range: bytes=61234-105678`. What I want to know is how to get what part of the audio in seconds corresponds with what range of of data bytes. What I have now takes a time range and plays (ex, 60-70seconds will play 10 seconds of the file) but it doesn't start at the right time in the file (the 60-70 sec example actually plays 13s - 23s). How do I calculate the range correctly?

Comment: @iKey you let the browser do that by using the `src'path/to/audio.mp3#t=60-100'` syntax. The browser will parse the metadata from the audio file by requesting the whole file from your server. It will then abort that request once it has successfully parsed the metadata (without downloading the whole file). Finally it will make an additional byte-range request with the correct offsets.